# grep returns no results

Tags: macos, bash, unix, grep

Came up to a strange problem - was running a trivial command

```
grep -F "INSERT" new.sql >& output.txt
```

on a `new.sql` that is 76MB large. The funny thing here is that none results are returned however the string is present there.

Current env is OSX 10.9.5, bash 3.2. `grep` is running with no problems on other files in the same env.

Could it be filesize/env related?

Somehow related question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19085/why-is-grep-o-w-not-giving-me-the-expected-output-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 3):

Found out that `grep` considers the file as `binary`, thus a workaround would be

```
cat new.sql | tr -d '\000' | grep -F "INSERT"
```

Source here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19907/what-makes-grep-consider-a-file-to-be-binary

Comment: You can use `grep -a` to make it treat binary files as text files.